# How to allow for files completition for the rest of _arguments?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I got `_arguments "1: :($(/usr/local/bin/aliases-drush.php))" \` working which is really great -- it's a PHP script printing one possibility for argument every line -- but the rest of the arguments can be local files and I tried to continue with  `'*:file:_files'` but it no longer completes argument 2, 3 etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
#compdef foo
local ret=1
_arguments \
  '1:first:(a b c)' \
  '*:files:_files' \
  && ret=0
return $ret
```

completes `a` `b` or `c` for me and then at least two files in testing. Changing the first argument handler

```
  '1: :($(print -l a b c))' \
```

likewise works for me. If you have spaces in the output of whatever your program does that will be a problem for the first argument completion, but does not break the subsequent files completion for me:

```
  '1: :($(< ~/tmp/opts))' \
```

and then:

```
 % print -l "a b" c d > ~/tmp/opts
 % rm ~/.zcompdump
 % exec zsh -l
 % foo
 a  b  c  d
```

it presents `a` or `b` not `a b`: usually one will instead see things like `${(f)"$(...)"}` to split only on newlines, `cd $fpath[-1]` usually will have the ZSH provided completion scripts to study.

But I cannot reproduce the "files completion not working" claim; perhaps with the full completion script and suitable output from the program?

Do note the `rm ~/.zcompdump ; exec zsh -l` commands that remove the completion cache and start a new ZSH instance, a less intrusive alternative may be a specific unload on the specific command name:

```
function zbouncecompdef { unfunction _$1; autoload -U _$1; }
```

Comment: Ah this works. I wrote `#compdef _drush drush  `function _drush { } ` and this wrapping killed the party. I didn't know you could put it top level like this, great! I found even the ret was not necessary.

Comment: completions get autoloaded as a function so there's no need to call them a function when they already are that

Comment: There's one problem: this works for the 1st, 2nd but not the third argument. I even added ret back. https://paste.gnome.org/phebhzjza https://paste.gnome.org/p6mdnlfj8

Comment: What do you expect and what doesn't work? With either of your functions, it will complete words from the output of aliases-drush.php for the 1st argument and files for the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th...nth. Are you only getting files in the second? What description if any is printed for the 3rd.

Comment: No description is printed, nothing happens.

Comment: And now it just works :( Mystery. I swear it didn't. Maybe I didn't reload properly.